# Error when working with Google Sheets Api

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets

Good day! At hand are two ways to obtain the first Credential is working properly to work with Google Drive Api, and demanded a permit for the first time:

```
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
            JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
            System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/drive_quickstart");
    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);


    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in =
                DriveQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                        .setAccessType("offline")
                        .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Drive client service.
     * @return an authorized Drive client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Drive getDriveService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Drive.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }
```

Then I use these methods to obtain a list of the documents available to me

```
Drive service = getDriveService();

        // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
        FileList result = service.files().list()
                .setPageSize(100)
                .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                .execute();
        List<File> files = result.getFiles();
        if (files == null || files.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No files found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Files:");
            for (File file : files) {
                System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
            }
        }
```

It works properly and correctly, but it took me further work directly with the tables (Google Sheets Api) By analogy Credential generated and brought to the console a list of available tables:

```
InputStream in =
                DriveQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println(
                "\"Credentials saved to" + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());

        SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MyAppName");
        service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);

        URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
                "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

        SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
        List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

        for (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet : spreadsheets) {
            System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText() + " " + spreadsheet.getId());
        }
```

But it turns out that when you create an instance of Spreadsheet Feed error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$SessionExpiredException: Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Token invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>

    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:570)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:652)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
    at TestAuthAndSheets.main(TestAuthAndSheets.java:71)
```

Tell me, please, in what could be the problem? There are also a method of obtaining Credentials other way, but it requires the hand each time O code that does not fit.

Comment: What is `SCOPES` here? You refer to it twice in your code, but haven't told us where it's defined or what its value is.

Comment: I've updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. The drive token has the wrong scope. 
`private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);` only requests access to the scope DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY, which is enough to view files, but not use the sheets api. What you are looking for is to add `SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS` to the list of scopes (SCOPES).